# capnpc::compile not writing files

Tags: rust, capnproto

I'm having difficulty working with the [capnpc crate](https://github.com/dwrensha/capnpc-rust). I'm running Arch Linux and have installed capnp from the AUR and compiled capnpc-rust from the github project and put it in `/usr/local/bin`. I can manually compile the .capnp file easily with the command

```
capnp compile -orust --src-prefix=capnp capnp/message.capnp
```

I tried cloning the capnpc project and compiling the .capnp test file in the test directory and that didn't work either. I'm not getting any errors (whereas earlier I was getting "File not found") so it seems like capnpc is working, but I can't find files anywhere.

build.rs

```
extern crate capnpc;
fn main() {
    ::capnpc::compile("capnp", &["capnp/message.capnp"]).unwrap();
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
...
build = "build.rs"

[lib]
name = "rustp2p"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[build-dependencies]
capnpc = "*"

[dependencies]
capnp = "0.5.0"
```

Edit: .rs file builds out into /target/debug/build/.../out.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. I noticed people were still answering when it is not needed. I'll remove the edit since it sounds like thats the stackoverflow way of doing things. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, I see. I only provided a comment which doesn't count as an answer. In fact, I tend to delete most of my comments after they have been added to a question / answer, and I will do so for these soon ^_^. The *creator* of the Rust capnproto library answered your question, so it's perfectly acceptable for that to be the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke capnpc::compile from a Cargo build script, the generated code goes in a subdirectory of target/ that can be found at main compile time through the `OUT_DIR` environment variable. This strategy is described in the [Cargo documentation](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#case-study-code-generation).

You shouldn't need to install the capnpc-rust binary in /usr/local/bin or anywhere else for this to work.

Your build.rs and Cargo.toml files look fine to me.

You might find it helpful to consult the [addressbook example](https://github.com/dwrensha/capnpc-rust/tree/master/example/addressbook).

Comment: I did actually have to install the "normal" binary, otherwise the `Command` invocation failed with "no such file or directory".

Comment: Right, you still do need to [install `capnp`](https://capnproto.org/install.html) on your system.